# Filemaker: Best way to set a certain field in every related record

Tags: filemaker

I have a FileMaker script which calculates a value. I have *1* record from table `A` from which a relation points to *n* records of table `B`. What is the best way to set `B::Field` to this value for each of these *n* related records?

Doing `Set Field [B::Field; $Value]` will only set the value of the **first** of the *n* related records. What works however is the following:

```
Go to Related Record [Show only related records; From table: "B"; Using layout: "B_layout" (B)]
Loop
    Set Field [B::Field; $Value]
    Go To Record/Request/Page [Next; Exit after last]
End Loop
Go to Layout [original layout]
```

Is there a better way to accomplish this? I dislike the fact that in order to set some value (model) programmatically (controller), I have to create a layout (view) and switch to it, *even though the user is not supposed to notice anything like a changing view*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

FileMaker always was primarily an end-user tool, so all its scripts are more like macros that repeat user actions. It nowhere near as flexible as programmer-oriented environments. To go to another layout is, actually, a standard method to manipulate related values. You would have to do this anyway if you, say, want to duplicate a related record or print a report.

So:

1. Your script is quite good, except that you can use the Replace Field Contents script step. Also add Freeze Window script step in the beginning; it will prevent the screen from updating.
2. If you have a portal to the related table, you may loop over portal rows.
3. FileMaker plug-in API can execute SQL and there are some plug-ins that expose this functionality. So if you *really* want, this is also an option.

I myself would prefer the first variant.

Comment: What’s different about the Replace Field Contents script step? I’ve never used it. Is it faster?

Comment: Yes, it's faster. It can only set a single field though, so for more complex changes (or conditional changes) it would be simpler to use a loop.

Comment: Ah I see: I can use `Replace Field Contents` _instead_ of the whole loop… Great!

Comment: Also: what about `Freeze Window`: do I have to explicitly call `Refresh Window` in the end or does it do that automatically after the script has executed?

Comment: No, you don't have to use `Refresh Window`; in the end of the script it will do it automatically. It will also refresh window when the script pauses in `Pause/Resume` script step. But it freezes almost anything else, so, for example, you can script going to another layout, entering Find mode and displaying a custom dialog to ask for search criteria, and the user won't notice any of this.

Answer (score 2):

**Loop through a Portal of Related Records**

Looping through a portal that has the related records and setting the field has a couple of advantages over either Replace or Go To Record, Set Field Loop.

1. You don't have to leave the layout. The portal can be hidden or place off screen if it isn't already on the layout.
2. You can do it transactionally. IE you can make sure that either all the records get edited or none of them do. This is important since in a multi-user networked solution, records may not always be editable. Neither replace or looping through the records without a portal is transaction safe.

Here is some info on [FileMaker transactions](https://www.geistinteractive.com/filemaker-transactions/).

You can loop through a portal using Go To Portal Row.  Like so:

```
Go To Portal Row [First]
Loop
    Set Field [B::Field; $Value]
    Go To Portal Row [Next; Exit after last]
End Loop
```

Comment: Thanks for the info on transactions. I don’t think I’ve ever had to work on a FileMaker database that was being used by multiple users at a time buy maybe someday I will have to.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what you're using the value for.  If you need to hard wire a certain field, then it doesn't sound like you've got a very normalised data structure.  The simplest way would be a calculation in TableB instead of a stored field, or if this is something that is stored, could it be a lookup field instead that is set on record creation?

What is the field in TableB being used for and how?

Comment: It’s a model of Offers, Goods and and Invoices. The field in question is Goods.has_been_invoiced.
There is also an intermediary table for the many-to-many relationship between Good and Invoice. Any Offer can contain many Goods and when creating a new invoice from an Offer, all not-yet invoiced Goods are copied to the intermediary table. The script in question is run on print of the invoice and sets has_been_invoiced to true on all goods appearing in the invoice.